# What is the meaning of '#'?

Tags: haskell

```
STM (State# RealWorld -> (#State# RealWorld, a#))
```

`#` does not show up in the list of Haskell operators and google is not yielding anything useful as well. `Ghci:>:t (#)` states: Variable not in scope.

So what does that character do? And why is it used in the above piece of code (from STM)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a language extension to even be able to use it, that's how special it is!

It doesn't do anything, it's just a special-looking character that the GHC people see to like using in the names of low-level-ish maybe-boxing-related things.

There's `(# a, b #)` which is the type of an unboxed tuple of `a` and `b`, which is what you're seeing there--it's not `( #State# , ...`, it's `(# State#, ...`.

Comment: What also confuses me is that there is mention of ``State#`` and ``#State#`` - are those both the same or is there a difference?

Comment: Ahhh! So there is no ``a#`` involved then, too?!?!! This might just be the proof that haskell parser is more intelligent at parsing as I am :)

Comment: You actually need two language extensions for this code: `UnboxedTuples` for the unboxed tuples and `MagicHash` to allow identifier names like `State#`.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for dropping the google-able name ``MagicHash``!

Comment: I found a good entry point explaining matters: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.3/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html